# Trying to compile x86 assembly with GCC but getting errors about missing parenthesis and "junk after expression"

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

Full disclosure the following code is for a homework, but I wrote the code I just need help figuring out why I'm getting several errors when trying to compile it (My professor never talked about GCC errors).

I wrote a function that returns the sum of the two largest members of an array of size 10. I've marked the lines 70 and 74:

```
function1:
    pushl   %ebp
    pushl   %ebx
    movl    $2, %ebx #ebx will be counter
    movl    %esp, %ebp #first will be %edx and second will be %eax
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx #first = arr[0]
    movl    (%edx,1,4), %eax #second = arr[1] **LINE 70**
    cmpl    %eax, %edx #if(arr[0] > arr[1]) don't jump
    jle .L6
.L7:
    movl    (8(%ebp),%ebx,4), %ecx #%ecx = next value to compare **LINE 74**
    cmpl    %ecx, %edx #if first > next don't jump
    jle .L8
    cmpl    %ecx, %eax #if second > next don't jump
    jle .L9
    cmpl    $9, %ebx #check if counter = 9
    je  .L10
    addl    $1, %ebx #counter++ 
    jmp .L7
.L6:
    movl %edx, %ecx #move arr[0] into %ecx
    movl %eax, %edx #first = arr[1]
    movl %ecx, %eax #second = arr[0]
    jmp .L7
.L8:
    movl %edx, %eax #move previous first into second
    movl %ecx, %edx #move new first into first
    addl $1, %ebx   #counter++
    jmp .L7
.L9:
    movl %ecx, %eax #move new second into second
    addl $1, %ebx   #counter++
    jmp .L7
.L10:
    addl %edx, %eax
    popl    %ebx
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

I am getting the following error messages:

```
assign3.s:70: Error: expecting `)' after scale factor in `(%edx,1,4)'
assign3.s:74: Error: missing ')'
assign3.s:74: Error: missing ')'
assign3.s:74: Error: junk `(%ebp),%ebx,4))' after expression
```

I appreciate the help and let me know how I can improve my questions in the future

Comment: What is `(%edx,1,4)` supposed to mean? What is `(8(%ebp,%ebx,4))` supposed to mean?  You made some syntax errors and only you (as the author of the code) can tell what you meant to write instead.

Comment: `(%edx,1,4)` is the location of the first element in the array. `(8(%ebp),%ebx,4) `is a way of accessing the array at index %ebx

Comment: Well, neither are valid addressing modes.  A scale/index/base operand has the form `displacement(base, index, scale)` where `displacement` is a constant or symbol, `base` and `index` are registers, and `scale` is 1, 2, 4, or 8.  `1` is not a register and `8(%ebp)` is not a register, so your syntax is incorrect.  Perhaps you meant `4(%edx)` for the first one and `8(%ebp, %ebx, 4)` in the second one, but I'm not quite sure.  It could be that you first need to load the value at `8(%ebp)` into a register so you can use it as a base register.

Comment: I will try your suggestions thanks! This is our first actual assignment in the semester where we have to compile code, and for the most part we have to learn outside of class for this course.

Comment: My suggestion to you is to always try to assemble and run your program while you write it so you catch errors as soon as you make them.  You spent a lot of time writing a long program without having ever tested it and now you might have made some systematic errors that might be rather annoying to fix.  If you assemble and run your code all the time during development, you catch such issues much quicker.

Comment: @fuz Another suggestion is to follow the language rules rather than just making up stuff. After all, this is computer programming, not poetry.

Comment: You are right @fuz and that really helped me when I deleted it all and started over I was testing it instead of fully writing the function blindly. And that is true @Raymond! There are rules that must be followed, but there's a creative aspect to solving problems with computer programming

Comment: @Mobyh The creativity is in your data structures and algorithm. Syntax does not admit creativity. Parsers are very specific about what they accept.

Comment: @RaymondChen see what you meant now. You are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to rework my code completely but thanks to @fuz I was able to find the proper solution. My problem was both in syntax and in understanding of registers and pointers. Here's the correct code:

```
function1:
    #FIRST %edx
    #SECOND %eax
    #THIRD  %ebx
    #LOCATION OF ARRAY %esi
    #COUNTER %edi
    pushl   %ebp
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   %edi
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    $1, %edi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    (%esi), %edx
    movl    (%esi, %edi, 4), %eax
    addl    $1, %edi
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    jle     .L6
.L7:
    movl    (%esi, %edi, 4), %ebx
    cmpl    %ebx, %edx
    jle     .L8
    cmpl    %ebx, %eax
    jle     .L9
.L11:
    addl    $1, %edi
    cmpl    $10, %edi
    jne     .L7
    jmp     .L10
.L6: #Switch FIRST and SECOND
    movl %edx, %ebx
    movl %eax, %edx
    movl %ebx, %eax
.L8: #THIRD is bigger than FIRST
    movl %edx, %eax
    movl %ebx, %edx
    jmp .L11
.L9: #THIRD is bigger than SECOND
    movl %ebx, %eax
    jmp .L11
.L10: #Add and return
    addl %edx, %eax
    popl    %edi
    popl    %esi
    popl    %ebx
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```